# Is there any difference using of these Strings in java?

Tags: java, string

In my program i am using **String** as like follow:

1. `String s1=null;` and
2. `String s1=new Sting();`

For first **String** later in some where i will change `s1="Demo Test"`. could anybody guide me that which way is best to use **String**?

Answer (score 1):

```
String s1 = new String();
```

is completely pointless, as all you are doing is creating an extra instance of `String` that will be discarded later.

```
String s1 = null;
```

is fine, but not necessary if you are not using the variable before it is initialized with the proper value.
A simple

```
String s1;
```

will usually do just fine.

Comment: `String s1;` != `String s1 = null;` in method-scope.

Comment: @Peter: No, it sure is not. I added some more info to (hopefully) clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The second option

```
String s1=new Sting();
```

would create a new empty String. It would probably take a little more memory and CPU time, but you will not notice a difference unless you do the same operation trillions of times.

On the other hand, in the second option the string exists and you can do stuff with it, for example concatenate another String to it:

```
s1 = s1 + " bla bla";
```

If you use the first option:

```
String s1=null;
s1 = s1 + " bla bla";
```

you would get a NullPointerException.

Other than this there are no differences I can see.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that when you create a string object using new String() it creates an empty string.

See Java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

> public String() Initializes a newly created String object so that it
>   represents an empty character sequence. Note that use of this
>   constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.

When you use String s1 = null; however it creates a String variable which points to nothing. Hence you can't invoke it like s1.length (this results in a NullPointerException) until you actually assign a value to s1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to modify a String in a loop or in a conditional situation and need the results outside of the brackets, you might need to use String s1 = null;

For example:

```
boolean test = true;
String s1 = null;
if (test) {
   s1 = "true";
} else {
   s1 = "false";
}
System.out.println("Results is: " + s1);
```

If you don't define s1 as being null before the condition, you will have an error when printing